# I just bought a specialized dolce bike and it has EN 14781 on it its a road bike but i dont know anything else

Tags: identify-this-bike

Picture of my bicycle . I just bought and I know it's a specialized bike and EN14781 was embossed on it like a model number.

Comment: Did you ask the seller?

Comment: EN14871 is not a serial number, but only an european certificate
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51927/what-does-en-14781-certificate-mean

Comment: BS EN 14781:2005 covers the test methods applicable in the design and manufacture of racing bikes. It was developed to ensure the strength and durability of individual parts as well as of the bicycle as a whole, demanding high quality throughout and consideration of safety aspects from the design stage onwards.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: Aside - the picture hasn't come through in your question.  Could you please try re-adding that?  Or paste a link to the photo elsewhere on the web, like imgur.com

Comment: The only thing to maybe be added to the existing answer right now, unless you can say something more specific, is that it's a perfectly competent entry level road bike. It would be nicer to have something with more gears in the back, but not necessary to enter the sport. Replacement components are easily available and it doesn't matter much what manufacturer or year. Consider this question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

A Dolce is one of Specialized's "female-specific" designs.  This one is a road bike with drop bars, and the stock photo shows:

[image]

The [company's page on this model](https://www.specialized.com/nz/en/dolce/p/154317?color=240230-154317) with specs.

The EN14781 certification was replaced in 2014, so your bike is no newer than 2014 at the most recent, and is newer than 2005 when the standard was introduced.

Comment: I suspect it could be a little newer - certainly don't rule out 2015 as the frame could have been made weeks to months before assembly.  The newer standard is (some parts of) [ISO 4210](https://www.bike-eu.com/laws-regulations/nieuws/2015/01/new-iso-standard-for-bicycles-implemented-1018946), which is structured differently, and came into force in 2015

Comment: @ChrisH true - the stock photo above is probably more recent than 2014 also... the seat stays have that wiggle.